# Permission denied for `ssh-add` in Git Bash, Windows 11

Tags: windows, git, ssh, permissions

I'm trying to set up Git on my work laptop, running Windows 11 21H2.
I've [downloaded git for Windows v.2.41.0.2](https://git-scm.com/download/win) (released on 7th July 2023) and completed the step-by-step installation (I've chosen to integrate Git Bash in Windows' Terminal app).

I'm closely following the ssh authentication process described in [the official GitHub docs for Windows](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent). I therefore launched Git Bash from Windows' Start menu as 'ordinary' user (no admin privileges), then generated the ssh key-pair in the `~/.ssh/` path, started the `ssh-agent` but when I do the following:

> Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent. If you created your key with a different name, or if you are adding an existing key that has a different name, replace id_ed25519 in the command with the name of your private key file.
>
> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

I get this error:

> $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/gitWIN
>
> bash: /usr/bin/ssh-add: Permission denied

Where `gitWIN` is the name of the private key from the keygen step.
What am I doing wrong?

Yesterday I still had the previous version of Git for Windows and proceeded without hitches up to SSH verification. Today however, Git Bash wasn't launching at all, nor was I able to do any `git pull` from my private repo on github so I decided to download the latest version of Git and re-install it but now I'm stuck at the SSH key-pair step.

---

### EDIT1

The output of the `ssh -Tv git@github.com` is a series of lines that terminate with -1, meaning "SSH couldn't find a file to use" as written in [the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey#getting-more-details) -- does anybody know how that gets fixed?

```bash
OpenSSH_9.3p1, OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023
...
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myuser>/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myuser>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myuser>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myuser>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/<myuser>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

---

### EDIT2

contents of `~/.ssh` directory:

```bash
$ ls -hal
total 27K
drwxr-xr-x 1 <myuser> 1049089    0 lug  9 16:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 <myuser> 1049089    0 lug  9 19:57 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 <myuser> 1049089  419 lug  9 16:16 gitWIN_id_ed25519
-rw-r--r-- 1 <myuser> 1049089  104 lug  9 16:16 gitWIN_id_ed25519.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 <myuser> 1049089 1,4K lug  9 12:48 known_hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 <myuser> 1049089  279 lug  9 12:37 known_hosts.old
```

*PS: I have generated other pairs of keys so this might look different from my original post above.*

Comment: Is there any SSH .config file that needs to be created or edited in the `~/.ssh/` folder in Windows?

Comment: If you have additional info/questions you should [edit] and add it there.

Comment: Can you please show text output of these commands: `ls -lAF /usr/bin/ssh-add` ? `/usr/bin/ssh-add --help` ?

Comment: here's the output of that command (this is still in Windows right?):

```bash
$ ls -lAF /usr/bin/ssh-add
-rwxr-xr-x 1 <myuser> 1049089 439889 lug  7 09:21 /usr/bin/ssh-add*
```

Comment: @phd I changed the permission to that file you indicated: `chmod a+w <file>` then tried starting the ssh-agent again and then adding the private key...it seems to have worked! Instead of giving a "Permission denied" msg, it now says: "Identity added.."

Comment: Unfortunately the SSH test still fails. I'm again getting `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Now when `ssh-agent`/`ssh-add` work it's time to run `ssh -Tv git@github.com` again to test the server knows your public key (you've uploaded the public key, have you?) and recognizes private key.

Comment: @phd yes have uploaded the public key (multiple times!) on my github.com account. I did some more digging and have found that, unlike git on Mac, git on Windows requires one to start the ssh-agent and then add the private key each time one wants to use git. Therefore I've saved a .bashrc in my $HOME folder (yes, in Windows). I'll write this stuff as the Solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly solved this issue but after changing permissions to the file indicated above by @phd (cf. Comments under the original question) I also created a hidden `.bashrc` file in my $HOME folder in Windows 11, following [the guidelines as in this external post](http://anterence.blogspot.com/2012/01/ssh-agent-in-msysgit.html) referenced in another Stackoverflow question.
Here's the content of such file:

```bash
$ cat .bashrc

#! /bin/bash
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/gitWIN_id_ed25519
```

After rebooting the machine this afternoon, it now successfully passes the ssh test on Git Bash (`ssh -T git@github.com`).

Hope this helps anyone else struggling with this problem.